# Should AuthnStatement be present in IdP initiated SAMLResponse

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

In the case of IDP Initiated FLow, Is the AuthnStatement is also mandatory in Assertion of the SAML Response?

Edit:
And what is bearer Assertion and what is its use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as we are talking about the **Authentication Request Protocol** which is used in **Web Browser SSO Profile** for both SP and IDP initialized single sign-on, the standard has the followng to say:

> In case profile doesn't override) The assertion(s)
>   returned MUST contain a  element that represents the
>   presenter. The identifier type and format are determined by the
>   identity provider. At least one statement in at least one assertion
>   MUST be a  that describes the authentication
>   performed by the responder or authentication service associated with
>   it. (2250-2253 core)

and

> The set of one or more assertions MUST contain at least one
>    that reflects the authentication of the principal to
>   the identity provider. (547-548 profiles)

So the answer is - depends on profile, some SAML profiles (including custom ones) may not require AuthnStatements, but the most typical SAML profile for web single sign-on (and the one you are most likely talking about) does require it for both SP and IDP initialized flow.

And to your second question - **bearer assertion** is such assertion which is using **bearer subject confirmation**.

**Subject confirmation** is piece of information which helps recipient of the assertion (relying party / service provider) verify that the presenter of the assertion (attesting party - e.g. browser, or API client, ...) is associated with its subject (about whom was the assertion issued) and authorized to present the assertion on subject's behalf (to make sure that someone cannot use assertion issued for someone else, without someone else's permission). The **bearer subject confirmation** simply means that the presenter of the assertion is the same as the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Few things are mandatory in SAML. Accordning to SAML AuthnStatement is not mandatory in any assertion. This is probably constrained in some way in the software you are using. If it is mandatory for Assertions in SP init flow I would guess it is mandatory in the IDP init flow to

Comment: Without AuthnStatement how the user can be believed to establish valid session at SP side?

Comment: From the spec "An assertion with no statements MUST contain a <Subject> element. Such an assertion identifies a
principal in a manner which can be referenced or confirmed using SAML methods, but asserts no further
information associated with that principal."

Comment: But your software does probably require an AuthnStatement